# Qt/Qml: how to make widget (createWindowContainer) fill parent widget

Tags: c++, ios, qt, webview, qml

I have this problem for months. I try to implement a webview on iOS with QtWebView by Qml and embed the webview into a widget by `QWidget::createWindowContainer` (following a online tutorial). But I just can't get this widget to fill the parent widget, nor change its size at all.

I have write the following minimal example for explaining the problem:

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *mainwindow = new QWidget();
    mainwindow->setStyleSheet("background-color:red;"); // so that we can see the problem more clearly

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(mainwindow);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
    QWidget* container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, mainwindow);
    // container->setMinimumSize(200, 200);
    // container->setMaximumSize(200, 200); // the displaying size doesn't change with or without these lines
    // container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///webview.qml"));

    layout->addWidget(container);
    mainwindow->setLayout(layout);

    mainwindow->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

webview.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtWebView 1.0

Item {
    visible: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    WebView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "https://www.google.de"
    }
}
```

When I run this mini program on iphonesimulator in QtCreator, the layout is like the following screenshots (sorry I can't embed the pictures yet):
[We can see the container doesn't fill the top area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkW3y.png). And even when the parent widget is much smaller (in my actual program), the container has always this same size. When I rotate the iphonesimulator, [it looks then like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmhjw.png).

Could anyone please help to solve this? It's annoying me for months. Thanks!

Comment: I have on Android tested, everything works and I can also change the size of the container. Is this a bug on iOS?

Comment: Hi, could you solve your problem ? I'm after the same question

Comment: @Leo Hi I could not solve the problem. That was a bug in QT of that version I think. Maybe they have correct it in the update, but I have not tested the project since then.

Comment: I reported this as an iOS bug, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57590

Comment: @Leo ok. you can post the answer here if they resolve the bug and I could then close the question.